# Show continents on the first tableview and then show countries for the selected continents in another tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, codable

I have a JSON like this and I need to parse it offline using a Codable model.
In my ViewController I have 2 tableviews, on the first one I have to show only the continents list, on the second tableview I have to show the countries list from the selected continent.

I also need to add a search function from a textfield text input

I can achieve it?

Here is my JSON:

```
{ 
    "Africa":[
        {
            "name":"Algeria",
            "alpha3Code":"DZA",
            "region":"Africa"
        }
]
}
```

Here is the codable model for parsing the offline JSON from the decoder

```
struct ModelMap: Codable {
    let africa: [Africa]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case africa = "Africa"
    }
}

// MARK: - Africa
struct Africa: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let alpha3Code: String?
    let region: String?
}

enum Region: String, Codable {
    case africa = "Africa"
}
```

Comment: please show the code you are using to achieve it and where are you having an issue

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Are you more asking for someone to do the coding for you? It seems to me, the first table view's data source requires to list out all of the continents. Then once a continent has been selected, the other table view should then receive the continents sub-array of countries to then be displayed. Yes, you can achieve this. You just need for your continent table view to be able to pass its countries to the countries table view. This can be achieved through MVVM.